# HAProxy add header on response doesn't work

Tags: haproxy

```
 frontend http-in
     bind *:8080
     default_backend proxies
 
 backend proxies
     timeout connect 5s
     timeout server 30s
     balance roundrobin
     http-response set-header X-Server-Data %s
 
     server server-0 server-0:8080 check maxconn 2
     server server-1 server-1:8080 check maxconn 2
```

Here is my haproxy config. Why I don't see `X-Server-Data` header on response? I need to get chosen backend name from it.

*HAProxy version 2.8.3-1~bpo12+1, released 2023/09/08*

Comment: are you in `mode http` or `mode tcp`? `http-response set-header` requires `mode http`